# Python Tkinter のボタン入力　関数を抜ける方法

Tags: python, tkinter

canvasの更新をしている関数をボタンからの入力によって抜けたい場合どのような方法がありますか？

```
def update():
   canvas.after(10,update)
```

のような関数に

```
if(ボタン押すorキー入力):
    return
```

を追加することを目標にしています。
ボタンがクリックされたか否かを判定する関数等ございましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

global関数で1つ変数を作り、そこで判定するようにしました。